# ERROR plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager after upgrading to 2.3.3

Tags: grails, plugins, upgrade, ubuntu-14.04, gvm

I upgrade my project using the following commands :

```
          ~$ gvm install grails 2.3.3
          ~$ gvm use grails 2.3.3
          ~$ cd myproject 
  myproject$ grails upgrade --force 
  myproject$ grails refresh-dependencies
  myproject$ grails clean
  myproject$ grails run-app
```

I made many attempts to avoid the following error messages without expected result :

```
| Error 2014-05-21 13:19:59,324 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager  - Error configuring dynamic methods for plugin [controllers:2.3.3]: String index out of range: 1
Message: String index out of range: 1
    Line | Method
->> 1934 | substring                     in java.lang.String
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    222 | getPropertyNameRepresentation in grails.util.GrailsNameUtils
|    303 | innerRun . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    138 | run                           in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|    895 | runTask . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|    918 | run                           in     ''
^    662 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/myproject
| Application loaded in interactive mode. Type 'stop-app' to shutdown.
| Enter a script name to run. Use TAB for completion:
```

When i browse to console plugin `http://localhost:8080/myproject/console` ,  i get :

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error
URI
/myproject/console
Class
java.lang.NullPointerException
Message
null
Trace
   Line | Method
->> 895 | runTask in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   918 | run     in     ''
^   662 | run . . in java.lang.Thread
```

and on terminal , i get :

```
| Error 2014-05-21 13:21:59,940 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] ERROR filter.UrlMappingsFilter  - Error when matching URL mapping [/(*)/(*)?/(*)?(.(*))?]:null
Message: null
   Line | Method
->> 895 | runTask in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   918 | run     in     ''
^   662 | run . . in java.lang.Thread
| Error 2014-05-21 13:21:59,944 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] ERROR [/monistation].[default]  - Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/monistation] threw exception
Message: null
   Line | Method
->> 895 | runTask in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   918 | run     in     ''
^   662 | run . . in java.lang.Thread
grails>
```

Known that BuildConfig.groovy includes the following plugins:

```
plugins {
    // plugins for the build system only
    build ":tomcat:7.0.47"

    // plugins for the compile step
    compile ":scaffolding:2.0.1"
    compile ':cache:1.1.1'
    compile ':console:1.3'
    compile ":jdbc-pool:7.0.47"
    // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
    runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.4" // or ":hibernate4:4.1.11.2"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.3.5"
    runtime ":jquery:1.10.2"
    runtime ":resources:1.2.1"
    runtime ':db-reverse-engineer:0.5'

    // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
    //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0.1"
    //runtime ":cached-resources:1.1"
    //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been fixed in grails 2.3.5